# Table name missing dataset after UNNEST event_params

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT ep.value FROM ep
                       WHERE ep.key = 'key_name') AS key_name
    FROM analytics_tables.events_20210824 e CROSS JOIN
        UNNEST(event_params) AS ep
    WHERE e.event_name = 'item_clicked' AND
        ep.key = 'my_key_type' and ep.value.int_value=7;
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> Table name "ep" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request

How should I reference "ep" in order for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT value FROM e.event_params
                       WHERE key = 'key_name') AS key_name
    FROM analytics_tables.events_20210824 e CROSS JOIN
        UNNEST(event_params) AS ep
    WHERE e.event_name = 'item_clicked' AND
        ep.key = 'my_key_type' and ep.value.int_value=7;
```

Comment: great! this was a blind shot as exact schema was not known to me. so glad it works for you! please also vote up the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You should set your database first before handling the table, otherwise it won't know to which database extract the data from.

```
USE database;
```

This solution has been extracted from the following [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart#create_a_database_and_upload_data).

Comment: Please note that analytics_tables.events_20210824 is working fine. "ep" is not a table, but just the result of the unnest, UNNEST(event_params) AS ep.